# How to fix "probeid = 337 Stack Dump = java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed, reason: RC: 107 Transport endpoint is not connected"

Tags: java, websphere

Our application runs in Websphere 6.1 and our business logic requires to invoke an external webservice. We are getting the subject mentioned exception intermittently.

Have done some research and found following possible reasons

The end point has some port ( 
http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM10292) - This shouldn't be the case because most of the request are working fine only some are failing.
Also this is mentioned as an issue for WAS 7 only, ours is WAS 6.1

```
Exception = java.io.IOException

Source = com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPTransportSender.invoke

probeid = 337

Stack Dump = java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed, reason: RC: 107  Transport endpoint is not connected

        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncChannel.multiIO(AbstractAsyncChannel.java:474)

        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.read(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:217)

        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.readAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:205)

        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:150)
```

Comment: Err, connect the endpoint before the operation?

Comment: Issue is resolved. With the help of the network team identified that the issue was due to low bandwidth for the particular traffic. that is why only few requests failed and others where working fine. issue occurs only when there is an network issue.